# Screen flickering very fast on Lenovo Legion 5

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I have tried using the default drivers, removing the nvidia drives and disabling my dgpu and using the intel igpu but it does this. However when I boot into recovery mode it works perfectly fine even when my dgpu is enabled. Any ideas on how to fix?

It flickers like this very fast.

[image: it flickers this very fast]

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; are you hoping we guess?   It looks like Ubuntu Desktop to me, but no clues as to release, what kernel stack you've opted to use (if LTS release and options exist) etc...  FYI:  I saw a user report issues with the new HWE stack (6.2 kernel) for 22.04 for example; a solution used by the user was to switch to the older GA kernel stack; but we have no actual specifics to suggest anything for yourself.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. I am running the latest kerbal (6.4.8 I tried 6.2 and hoped updating would fix ) on 22.04 and have a Lenovo legion i5 with a rtx3070 as the gpu. Hope that helps